# Am i fragmenting the heap? And how not to or otherwise be better

Tags: c++, memory-management, arduino, esp8266

I'm working in C++ for Arduino running on an ESP8266.

I have a long lived object which maintains two collections of sub-objects (two different types).

These two collections will have the order of ~5-20 elements each by the end of the long-lived object's life, although the upper bound is not fixed. Realistically it won't be much more than 20 if it ever is, it won't be 100 for example.

My code for maintaining each collection looks like this (only showing one here for brevity):

```
void MyLongLivedObject::addSubObject(SubObject* obj)
{
    SubObject** newColl = new SubObject*[this->collectionCount + 1];
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < this->collectionCount ; i++)
        newColl[i] = this->collection[i];
    delete this->collection;
    this->collection = newColl;

    this->collection[this->collectionCount++] = obj;
}
```

Is my understanding right that as each of the two collections are expanded by adding objects, they are moved to  the end of the heap memory, leaving a hole? So if I were to alternate adding objects to each collection they would basically walk their way down the heap?
And then maybe at some point the hole at the start of the heap would be large enough to accommodate one of the collections and it would get moved back there.

I know the question of "is this a good idea?" is subjective and will depend on many things. To avoid that, can I instead ask for input on how to answer this question myself? What things should I be considering, how do I determine if this is acceptable or not? What questions do I need to answer to be comfortable with this implementation (i.e. to not horribly fragment the heap and cause related woe)?

Alternatively - if this whole approach is rubbish, what should I be doing instead?

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself, do you really need to store *pointers* to the ? SubObject` class? The second is, does the Arduino framework not have its own "dynamic array" class that you can use instead, or if not why not use `std::vector` (if it's available)?

Comment: Then you also have *undefined behavior* because you use `delete` to match `new[]`, when you should be using `delete[]`.

Comment: And yes, allocating and reallocating will lead to fragmentation. You can eliminate *some* fragmentation by allocating in chunks instead. So if you know you will end up with at least `5` elements, why not allocate `5` elements at a time? Sure it will waste a little memory, but that little waste could help save memory later due to the fragmentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why do I have undefined behaviour? If i `delete[]` them when growing the array, then ive' deleted them? Thats not what I want?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude re dynamic arrays, no, not unless I import some external lib. And wont that just have the same problem i have?

Comment: @stark Do you know what Arduino on the esp8266 does in this respect? I'll have a read

Comment: `new` must be matched with `delete`, and `new[]` must be matched with `delete[]`. You use `new[]` and `delete`. The statement `delete this->collection;` should be `delete[] this->collection;`

Comment: sorry, my comment did not apply to arduino

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wont `delete[]` call `delete` on the `SubObject`s in the array? I dont want this?

Comment: @AndrewBullock No that's not how it works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude straight from cplusplus.com: "An expression with the delete[] operator, first calls the appropriate destructors for each element in the array (if these are of a class type), and then calls an array deallocation function."

Comment: @AndrewBullock But pointers doesn't have destructors! Only the *pointers themselves* are being "destructed", not what they point to.

Comment: I know this question is old, but my comment is:  Never use dynamic allocation in a microcontroller application if it must run a long time.  Anything other than a toy or hobby project should never use dynamic allocation, period.  I write this as a holder of several patents for FDA-approved electronic *medical devices*.  Such devices cannot be allowed to fail, *EVER*.  If you don't design it to never fail, it will fail.

Comment: @TomServo thanks for your response. I'm really struggling with your recommendation and it's implications. I've read lots of blogs and posts which share your sentiment, but none offer any practical solutions. If I want to have N things, where N is dynamically determined at runtime, what _should_ I do? N will have some realistic upper limit, but i'm not going to preemptively allocate all that RAM when I almost certainly wont need all of it. I don't accept "tough sh*t, thats embedded land" which is a very common response. We have a heap, we can be competent, we can test and peer review code

Comment: @AndrewBullock I know what you're feeling.  The question is, what if you need *n+1* objects and you can't allocate due to either insufficient heap, or fragmented heap?  That is the rub.  In safety- and life-critical applications, this is a serious problem and if it can't be solved to the satisfaction of regulators, your design will be invalidated. I don't know much about automotive, for example, but I'd wager that the ABS controller on your vehicle does *not* do dynamic allocation of anything.  Your expectations on reliability may vary, of course.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm not arguing about the importance of saftey and how that might force design/implementaiton decisions. I just find blanket avoiding implementation because of "fear" silly, especailly when there isnt even discussion of alternative methods. I'd prefer to way options up instead of just avoiding one because "reasons".
In my situation at least I can easily deal with N+1, it can have some sensible max value. Just what do you do memory wise up to that point? Not trying to be a dick, i genuinely want to know what the approaches are